# Most elegant way to modify elements of nested lists in place

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a 2D list that looks like this:

```
table = [['donkey', '2', '1', '0'], ['goat', '5', '3', '2']]
```

I want to change the last three elements to integers, but the code below feels very ugly:

```
for row in table:
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        row[i+1] = int(row[i+1])
```

But I'd rather have something that looks like:

```
for row in table:
    for col in row[1:]:
        col = int(col)
```

I think there should be a way to write the code above, but the slice creates an iterator/new list that's separate from the original, so the references don't carry over.

Is there some way to get a more Pythonic solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for row in table:
    row[1:] = [int(c) for c in row[1:]]
```

Does above look more pythonic?

Comment: While this is technically an in-place operation, **two** extra lists are being created inside the loop. The first is created by the `row[1:]` slice (argument to `map`). The second is created by the use of a list comprehension.

Comment: This is called "list comprehensions" [https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions]

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
>>> for row in table:
...     row[1:]=map(int,row[1:])
... 
>>> table
[['donkey', 2, 1, 0], ['goat', 5, 3, 2]]
```

AFAIK, assigning to a `list` slice forces the operation to be done in place instead of creating a new `list`.

Comment: Is it still considered pythonic to use map over a comprehension?

Comment: @Nicholas Mancuso: I think both are similar in terms of performance. I would argue `map` is not less readable (especially if you familiar with functional programming). So, I guess it comes down to personal preference. I use both, whichever one looks simpler in that particular context is best IMHO. Although AFAIK, Guido thinks list comprehensions are better. But I don't see any objective reason for that.

Comment: I like map, but always get docked points from PyLint when I use it compared to the comprehensions, so I just stopped using it. Objectively there are no benefits of one over the other, but who can deny the Benevolent Dictator For Life?

Comment: @Nicholas Mancuso `map` is completely pythonic. What's not pythonic is the tangled mess that you often get when you try to jam too much into a `lambda` to use with it.

Comment: map used to be faster when used with builtin functions (such as int()), but I think LC's closed the gap a while back. For less experienced programmers the LC is definitely easier to read/understand

Comment: I was trying to get this in one line. Tried `map(lambda row: map(int, row[1:]), table)`, but how can I assign it back to `table`?

Comment: @ajmartin: just do `table[::]=` to whatever expression you use. this makes it do the operation in place.

Comment: @MAK: why the extra `:` in your last comment and in the second line of your answer? it is not needed, and is noise.

Comment: While this is technically an in-place operation, **two** extra lists are being created inside the loop. The first is created by the `row[1:]` slice (argument to `map`). The second is created by `map`. The space usage is *3n-1* for a `row` of length *n*. As *n* increases, the use of a simple inner loop becomes more space-efficient.

Answer (score 8):

I like Shekhar answer a lot.

As a general rule, when writing Python code, if you find yourself writing f`or i in range(len(somelist))`, you're doing it wrong:

- try `enumerate` if you have a single list
- try `zip` or `itertools.izip` if you have 2 or more lists you want to iterate on in parallel

In your case, the first column is different so you cannot elegantly use enumerate:

```
for row in table:
    for i, val in enumerate(row):
        if i == 0: continue
        row[i] = int(val)
```

Comment: "if you find yourself writing `for i in range(len(somelist))`, you're doing something wrong" --- This is probably the best advice that someone can give to a person learning the pythonic idioms.  Python's strength is what it gives you in readability, and when someone transitions from a lang like Java where this construct is typical they'll really miss out on the true advantages to working in Python. +1

Comment: You could improve it a little with `for i, val in enumerate(row[1:]):` and thus getting rid of the `if i == 0`

Comment: @erickrf this creates a shallow copy of the row, and afterwards you need to use row[i+1] = int(val). Not sure if this improves a lot.

Comment: The correctness of  "if you find yourself writing `for i in range(len(somelist))`, you're doing something wrong" is questionable.  Enumerate is not only slower, but may also be considered less readable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990189/1059398)  for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Your "ugly" code can be improved just by calling `range` with two arguments:

```
for row in table:
    for i in range(1, len(row)):
        row[i] = int(row[i])
```

This is probably the best you can do if you insist on changing the items in place without allocating new temporary lists (either by using a list comprehension, `map`, and/or slicing). See [Is there an in-place equivalent to 'map' in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148375/is-there-an-in-place-equivalent-to-map-in-python)

Although I don't recommend it, you can also make this code more general by introducing your own in-place map function:

```
def inplacemap(f, items, start=0, end=None):
    """Applies ``f`` to each item in the iterable ``items`` between the range
    ``start`` and ``end``."""
    # If end was not specified, make it the length of the iterable
    # We avoid setting end in the parameter list to force it to be evaluated on
    # each invocation
    if end is None:
        end = len(items)
    for i in range(start, end):
        items[i] = f(items[i])

for row in table:
    inplacemap(int, row, 1)
```

Personally, I find this *less* Pythonic. There is preferably only one obvious way to do it, and this isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions:

```
table = [row[0] + [int(col) for col in row[1:]] for row in table]
```

Comment: +1 I had no idea you could chain list comprehensions together like that!  I probably won't be using something this nested because I work with a lot of people that might find this unreadable, but I'll definitely keep this in mind for personal projects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
table = [[row[0]] + [int(v) for v in row[1:]] for row in table]
```

However you might want to think about doing the conversion at the point where the list is first created.

Comment: You're right.  treating my table with a special sub-table inside of it has been pretty cumbersome in all my other algorithms so I've got a raw data table now.

Answer (score -1):

This accomplishes what you are looking for. It is a readable solution. You can go for similar one using listcomp too.

```
>>> for row in table:
...     for i, elem in enumerate(row):
...             try:
...                     int(elem)
...             except ValueError:
...                     pass
...             else:
...                     row[i] = int(elem)
...
```

Comment: The only answer with proper validation in place. Though performing int cast twice is wasteful and defeats the idea behind try-except block