# range(len(list)) or enumerate(list)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, list-comprehension

Which of these would be considered better/clearer/faster/more 'Pythonic'? I don't care about the content of the list `L`, just how long it is.

```
a = [f(n) for n, _ in enumerate(L)]
```

or

```
a = [f(n) for n in range(len(L))]
```

If it makes any difference, the function `f` makes use of `len(list)` as well.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Some quick timing runs seem to give the 2nd option using `range()` a slight edge over `enumerate()`:

```
timeit a = [f(n) for n, _ in enumerate(mlist)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 us per loop

timeit a = [f(n) for n in range(len(mlist))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 us per loop
```

and just for fun using `xrange()` (Python v2.7.2)

```
timeit a = [f(n) for n in xrange(len(mlist))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 99 us per loop
```

I would favor *readable code first*, then using `xrange()` if available (i.e., Pre-Python v 3.x), followed by `range()` and `enumerate()`.

Comment: enumerate is faster when you want to repeatedly access the list items at their index. When you just want a list of indices, it is faster to to use len() and range/xrange.

Answer (score 8):

The (x)range solution is faster, because it has less overhead, so I'd use that.

In Python 2.x, use `xrange` instead of `range`, because `xrange` uses less memory, because it doesn't create a temporary list. In Python 3.x, there is only `range`, which is the less-memory version.

Thus, in Python 2.x, iterating over a `range(n)` uses *O(n)* memory temporarily, and iterating over an `xrange(n)` uses *O(1)* memory temporarily. Runtime is *O(n)* for both.

Comment: Is `xrange` a generator object? The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) makes no mention of that word, though your description sounds like it is.

Comment: It's not a generator object (i.e. pure Python code with `yield` in its body), but it's equivalent to that, implemented in C. It has a `.next()` method which returns the next value or raises StopIteration, and the `for` loop calls this `.next()` method repeatedly. (Please vote up my answer if you find it useful.)

Comment: nitpick: range does not create a temporary list, it creates a temporary range. So only constant time overhead when using range over xrange.

Comment: @PeterZeller: What `range` returns (list or range object) depends on the Python version (2.x or 3.x). This is correctly reflected in the answer. Your statement *range does not create a temporary list* is incorrect for Python 2.x. I've extended the answer with O(...) for both memory and time.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that as you aren't using the "_" attribute from the enumarate function then use range as it is more readable that way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Python 2.x, if you use `len()`, you should use `xrange()` as it will avoid creating a list of the numbers in the range.

And in this case, I'd go with `len()` because you are using the indices, not the items in the list.