# indexing with list comprehensions? Is it possible?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

The way I'm doing this now seems really clunky.  Is there a better way to index this array?

This is the code that works:

```
DEM = np.empty((number_of_DEM_files, DEMfile.shape[0], DEMfile.shape[1]), 'float')

for t in range(number_of_DEM_files):
      DEM[t] = np.load(DEM_filename_list[t])
```

I tried doing it with list comprehensions like this:

```
DEM = np.load([DEM_filename_list[t] for t in range(number_of_DEM_files)])
```

but I get a syntax error.  Is this possible?  Is there even a reason to do this or is it just as slow as what I've already got?  Is there a better way?

EDIT:

DEM_filename_list looks like this:

```
DEM_filename_list = (D:/Documents/Data/grand_canyon_2015/03-11/dem1.npy,
                     D:/Documents/Data/grand_canyon_2015/03-11/dem2.npy,
                     D:/Documents/Data/grand_canyon_2015/03-11/dem3.npy,
                     etc)
```

The first line creates an empty 3d array.  Ultimately, I'm trying to load and store a time series of arrays in one 3d array, so that you can index it with
DEM[t,i,j]

where t is the time, i is row number, and j is the column number.

Comment: What's the type of `DEM_filename_list`?

Comment: unrelated but `DEM_filename_list[:number_of_DEM_files]` would do the same as your list comp

Comment: Are you are missing an underscore in `number_of_DEM Files` ?

Comment: I don't think doing a simple `for` for this is clunky, although I didn't understand what the first line does.

Comment: What about `DEM = [np.load(f) for f in DEM_filename_list]`? Do you want to build a matrix with row values from different files?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that `np.load` does not take a list of filenames.  It takes one name.  But you can collect the results of the load into a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a testable example, which workes fine:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2))
b = np.array((3,4))

with open('12', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f,a)
with open('34', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f,b)    

l = DEM_filename_list

DEM = [np.load(ll) for ll in l]

print DEM
```

**Output:**

```
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Or presented with your annotations:

```
import numpy as np

DEM = [np.load(ll) for ll in DEM_filename_list]

print DEM
```

**Output:**

```
 DEM_files
```

**UPDATED:**

There is no need for the row:

```
DEM = np.empty((number_of_DEM_files))
```

Comment: DEM is then no longer a numpy array. You might want to do something like: `DEM = np.empty((2,2)); DEM[:] = [np.load(ll) for ll in l]` instead.

Comment: True, I updated, thanks. Note, that as I wrote in the update, there is no need any action before the assigning.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if **number_of_DEM_files** has a direct relation to **DEM_filename_list**, I assume it is one to one and DEM_filename_list is iterable (going by name), in that case I would do something like this.

```
DEM = np.empty((number_of_DEM_files, DEMfile.shape[0], DEMfile.shape[1])

for i, t in enumerate(DEM_filename_list):
      DEM[i] = np.load(t)
```

or

```
DEM = [np.load(t) for t in DEM_filename_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function do get an enumerate object of (index, value) and use the index in the resulting pair.

If performance is an issue you can use the numpy enumerate function: [ndenumerate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate).

Comment: Don't do this in numpy. It'll cause you to lose all of the performance gain you get from vectorization.

Comment: You get similar performance from range as from enumerate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990105/rangelenlist-or-enumeratelist